# Posso oferecer uma Gratificação por estar Grato?

Tags: debate

Eu fiz uma pergunta e obtive uma resposta que a responde muito bem e outra que me ajudou bastante, então estava pensando em aceitar uma resposta e dar uma Gratificação (Recompensa) para a outra. Isso seria má utilização do recurso do site? Eu estaria indevidamente atraindo atenção para minha pergunta que não precisa de novas respostas?

Minha intenção era dar a Gratificação imediatamente para a resposta que me ajudou, mas, parece que o período mínimo de duração é de 1 dia. Eu li [na central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) sobre as Recompensas, mas lá só fala sobre essas Recompensas serem para atrair melhores respostas, não trata dos casos em que quero simplesmente recompesar uma resposta que já tive.

Comment: Inclusive você pode dar uma gratificação em uma pergunta antiga de outrem se você ficar grato com a resposta

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum. Eu já recebi algumas recompensas embora a minha resposta não tenha sido marcada com  ✓.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você não pode oferecer uma recompensa antes do período mínimo de espera (2 dias), mas depois de oferecer poderá dar para quem quiser logo em seguida a 1 dia. Eu sugiro deixar os 7 dias para as pessoas terem mais chance de ver essa resposta tão boa, mas o critério é seu. Se esquecer de dar a recompensa será dada para a resposta de maior votação que foi dada após a recompensa ser estabelecida (o que é uma falha do sistema), mas apenas metade do valor será repassado.

Você quem escolhe pra qual resposta vai os pontos da recompensa, só gostaríamos que desse pra quem merece mesmo.

Existe um motivo quando vai oferecer a recompensa que justamente diz que uma ou mais respostas foram excepcionais. Mas você não pode dar a recompensa para mais que uma resposta, pode dar uma segunda recompensa depois, mas ela terá que ser 50 pontos a mais que a anterior, até o limite de 500.

Comment: "O período da gratificação dura 7 dias. As gratificações devem ter uma duração mínima de 1 dia." isso não significa que tenho que esperar ao menos um dia para dar a recompensa? E quanto ao que o @ramaral falou, não é possível aceitar uma resposta e dar uma recompensa à outra?

Comment: @Douglas eu estava errado, já eliminei o comentário.

Comment: @Douglas foi o que eu quis dizer, mas não ficou claro, melhorei agora. É possível dar a recompensa para quem quiser, tem vários casos no site, ele está equivocado.